# JSON deserialization of datetime - accepted format

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I have an Apex REST API endpoint prepared that accepts DTO object. One of the fields in this object is of Datetime type.

I was surprised that `JSON.deserializeStrict` accepts datetime to be of following format: `999999` which translates into `+999999-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`. Standard Salesforce API obviously works differently. Salesforce seems to be too flexible here for us.

Sample object definition:

```
public class MyObject {
    public Datetime startTime {get; set;}
}
```

Deserialization:

```
String jsonString = '{ "startTime": "99999"}';
MyObject ohmy = (MyObject) JSON.deserializeStrict(jsonStr, MyObject.class);
```

1. Does anyone know what all formats of datetime that are acceptable for JSON deserialization?
2. Is there any way of limiting it to work in the same way as Standard REST API ([Valid Date and DateTime Formats](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_valid_date_formats.htm)) other than custom validation in Apex of incoming request?

Comment: 1: While not explicitly documented, it is thought to be ISO 8601. Both `System.JSONGenerator` and `System.JSONParser` are documented to be using 8601. 2: No 3: If it's using 8601  String `999999` isn't a valid 8601 spec....but there's a [nuance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408249/how-do-you-represent-forever-infinitely-in-the-future-in-iso8601)